# How to disable an element based on ajax error respond

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've `form` with single input field `name` and with jquery i'm checking the name availability before submit and it gives either error message if didn't passed the check or gives message `correct` if passed the check out.

**Now my question** i wonder if this code can be adjusted so that it disable `submit` in case it didn't passed the availability check

or whatever so that it prevent clicking on submit button if didn't passed availability check.

**I'm using the following**

**Form Code**

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#name").change(function() {
var usr = $("#name").val();

if(usr.length >= 4){
$("#status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "check.php",
    data: "name="+ usr,
    success: function(msg){

   $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){

    if(msg == 'OK'){
        $("#username").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
        $("#username").addClass("object_ok");
        $(this).html('&nbsp;correct');
    }else{
        $("#username").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
        $("#username").addClass("object_error");
        $(this).html(msg);
    }
   });
 }
  });
}else{
    $("#status").html('<font color="red">The name should have at least 4 characters.</font>');
    $("#username").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
    $("#username").addClass("object_error");
    }
});
});
</SCRIPT>

<div id='myform'>
Name <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><div id="status"></div>
<br />
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

~ thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply disable the submit input element:

```
$("#submit").prop('disabled', true);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TChNs/)